# Attempt to index nil with Position

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to do something like a spear throw and I'm so confused. It says:

> ServerScriptService.FireMagic.FireSpear:16: attempt to index nil with 'Position'

Anyways, here's the LocalScript code:

```lua
wait(1)

local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local Character = Player.Character

local Mouse = Player:GetMouse()

local rp = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local FireSpear = rp:WaitForChild("FireRemote")

local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")

local debounce = true
local cd = 10

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, isTyping)
    if isTyping then
        return
    elseif input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E and debounce and Character then
        debounce = false
        
        FireSpear:FireServer()
        
        wait(cd)
        debounce = true
    end
end)
```

and the Script:

```lua
wait(1)

local rp = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local ss = game:GetService("ServerStorage")
local Debris = game:GetService("Debris")

local ssFireSpear = ss.FireMagic:WaitForChild("ssFireSpear")
local FireRemote = rp:WaitForChild("FireRemote")

local UhTable = {}

local function LookatMouse(Mouse, RootPart)
    local bodyG = Instance.new("BodyGyro")
    bodyG.MaxTorque = Vector3.new(0, 500000, 0)
    bodyG.P = 10000
    bodyG.CFrame = CFrame.new(RootPart.Position, Mouse.Position)
    bodyG.Parent = RootPart
    Debris:AddItem(bodyG, 1)
    
end

local function MoveTowardsMouse(Mouse, Main)
    local bodyV = Instance.new("BodyVelocity")
    bodyV.MaxForce = Vector3.new(500000, 500000, 500000)
    bodyV.Velocity = CFrame.new(Main.Position, Mouse.Position).LookVector * 100
    bodyV.Parent = Main
    
    local bodyG = Instance.new("BodyGyro")
    bodyG.MaxTorque = Vector3.new(500000, 500000, 500000)
    bodyG.P = 10000
    bodyG.CFrame = CFrame.new(Main.Position, Mouse.Position)
    bodyG.Parent = Main
end

FireRemote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(Player, Mouse_CFrame)
    if UhTable[Player.Name] == true then
        return
    end
    
    UhTable[Player.Name] = true
    
    local Character = Player.Character
    local RootPart = Character:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart")
    
    local folder = workspace:FindFirstChild("DebrisFolder") or Instance.new("Folder",workspace)
    folder.Name = "DebrisFolder"
    
    local RightHand = Character:WaitForChild("RightHand")
    
    local FireSpear = ssFireSpear:Clone()
    
    local Handle = FireSpear:WaitForChild("Handle")
    local Hitbox = FireSpear:WaitForChild("Hitbox")
    local Mesh = FireSpear:WaitForChild("Mesh")
    FireSpear:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(RightHand.CFrame)
    FireSpear.Parent = folder
    
    local weld = Instance.new("Motor6D")
    weld.Parent = Handle
    weld.Part0 = RightHand
    weld.Part1 = Handle
    
    Hitbox:SetNetworkOwner(nil)
    
    local function MakeStuffHappen()
        spawn(function()
            LookatMouse(Mouse_CFrame,RootPart)
            wait(.6)
            weld:Destroy()
            MoveTowardsMouse(Mouse_CFrame,Hitbox)
        end)
    end
    
    MakeStuffHappen()
    
end)
```

I'm following a tutorial but I don't know how the issue got there.

Comment: Either `Mouse` or `RootPart` is `nil`.

Comment: if it were, I believe a red kine would pop up, or in script analysis, say unknown global

Comment: why would it say "unknown global" if you index a local nil value? what you believe is irrelevant. there are two things you index with Position in line 16. Mouse and RootPart. So make sure they're not nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is pointing to the fact that you are trying to reference fields on an object that doesn't exist. In this case, it's the ´Mouse´ object, which you never supplied from the client.

To fix this, pass the mouse information in when you call the RemoteEvent's FireServer() function.

```
UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(input, isTyping)
    if isTyping then
        return
    elseif input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E and debounce and Character then
        debounce = false
        local mouseCFrame = Mouse.Hit
        FireSpear:FireServer(mouseCFrame)
        
        wait(cd)
        debounce = true
    end
end)
```

Comment: In my case, i need to get the mouse position after pressing the key, would this get the position after pressing the key or before?

Comment: After. First, any input causes this callback fires. If that input was "E", next the Mouse's position in 3d space is sampled, finally the FireRemote RemoteEvent is fired up to the server.